# Multiple POST requests to same file from same IP

Tags: php, post

I periodically check my apache domlog to check for anomalies in GET and POST requests.  Earlier today I noticed the same POST request to a login php happening once and sometimes twice a second for 2-3 hours from the same IP.  I am assuming it is someone trying to hack into an account.

So the question is:  What is the best way to guard against this?  I could blacklist the IP but I notice some people advise against this, since the IP could be dynamically changing.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement some form of [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) in [php](http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Cross-Site-Request-Forgery-%28CSRF%29-Attacks-in-PHP) wherein you include a random string token generated for each session in the form. this makes login requests invalid if the token generated by your server is not included in the request.

Comment: Thanks, this was a good answer and it led me to this link http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms .  The website in question is actually using Joomla which I should have mentioned in the question.  But I suppose this is important information for anyone not using Joomla as well.